# Strange Python performance degradation after running a long time and consuming large memory footprint

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a program to crunch some data about 2.2 million records. For each record, it will pass through a series of 20 computations that takes about total 0.01 second. To make it run faster, I use Python multiprocess, break my data generally into 6 blocks and run them in parallel with a master process distributing payloads to the processes and coordinating execution. BTW, as a result of the computations, the program will write out about 22 millions records to database.

I'm running this on a MacBookPro i7 2.2GHz with 8GB RAM running on Python 3.2.2. The data is on a local MySQL server.

The program starts well - running in an predictable manner, CPU on average is 60-70% utilized and my Macbook Pro just heats up like an oven. Then it slows down after running for about 5 hours with CPU utilization drops to average 20% on each core. Some observations I made then are:
- each Python process is consuming about 480 MB real RAM and about 850 MB virtual RAM. There are total 6 of these heavy processes
- The total virtual memory consumed by OSX (as shown by Activity Monitor) is about 300GB

I suspect the performance degradation is due to huge memory consumption and potentially high page swaps.

How can I better diagnose these symptoms? 
Is there any problem with Python running with large in-memory objects for long period of time? Really I don't think running 6 hours is heavy for today's technology but heck I am only about half a year of Python experience, so... what do I know?!

Thanks!

Comment: I'd wonder if you'd be able to do those computations on the database itself with stored procedures and eliminate the middle tier and network latency. 2.2 million records is a lot of bytes to move back and forth just for the sake of some calculations. Could the database do them?

Comment: I've considered that option but no. The reason why I choose Python is speed to program. The series of 20 computations is only a start and will likely grow very quickly. Doing them as a stored procedure may solve my performance issue now but it will slow me down in terms of implementing additional computation plugin logic. I have also tried to comment out the db write-back of 22 million records, it doesn't help much.

Comment: No matter which way you decide to go, sounds like you'll have to do it and commit in chunks.  The rollback segment for 2.2M records is too large.

Comment: I create a generator function to read the 2.2 million rec using a cursor running a "select * from table order by date". Then I iterate through the cursor and batch the data (by detecting date change) and return a batch at a time using yield. The maximum number of records for a batch is about 1000 and I assume memory will be garbage collected because all objs are local function scope.
I know other languages like Java JDBC has cursor type that will read all data into the memory to support random access. I initially suspect that may be the default behavior of my cursor but I don't think so now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the performance drop is because it is swapping stuff in and out of memory. I don't think the issue is how long the program is running - Python uses a garbage collector, so it doesn't have memory leaks.

Well, that's not *entirely* true. The garbage collector will make sure that it deletes anything that isn't reachable. (In other words, it will not delete something that you could conceivably access.) However, it's not smart enough to detect when a data structure won't be used for the rest of the program; you may need to clarify by setting all references to it to `None` that for it to work correctly.

1. Could you post the code involved?
2. Is this a program where you need a given record more than once? Is the order that you load records important for your program?
3. If the python process has only a few gigabytes of memory allocated, then why do you have 300 GB of used memory?

Comment: sorry, the code will be too long, I'll explain the design.
The program uses a lot of generator function because the next value computation always needs some earlier values/states. From the reading of db records to the 20 computations, every of them is performed through a generator function encapsulated in a their respective object. Currently I have about 1000 (different datastreams) x 20 (computation) objects. Each datastream is a distinct product and I'm performing regression and analytics for all of them by iterating chronologically.

Comment: As to your pt 3. I have no clue, that's why I tag this question to Python and OSX :)
I'm quite new to Python, is there any good guide out there on how to troubleshoot memory and performance problem?

Comment: I think I found the problem. The query of 2.2 million records actually takes up 2.6 GB of memory on a Python process. Apparently the pymysql driver doesn't support (or maybe I use it wrongly) retrieving data from the DB via an open cursor connection. I suspect it caches the full result set before it returns the first record.